# SSRS Previous Month Name

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2017

I need to get the previous month's name. E.g.

```
January --> December
July --> June
```

I tried using this:

```
=IIF(MONTH(Globals!ExecutionTime) = 1, "DECEMBER", MONTHNAME(MONTH(Globals!ExecutionTime)-1))
```

But this returns `#Error` when it is January. I'm assuming it's because the right else section of the `IIF` is still being evaluated even though the first part of the IIF returns TRUE.

Is there a better way to do this?

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 to make my SSRS report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be mixing up T-SQL and VB. You want to use the DateTime methods `AddMonths` and `ToString` provided:

```
=Globals!ExecutionTime.AddMonths(-1).ToString("MMMM");
```